# How to migrate/clone WhatsApp messages to Signal

Tags: python, shell, formatting, migration, whatsapp

As we know that, now and onward WhatsApp is not trustable app, Hence I want to copy history messages to Signal app.

I tried to Export chat from WhatsApp and paste on Signal with the make formatting, but only problem is Signal consider single message and not separate User1 and User2 conversation on ziczac format. .. it's a normal behaviour of all communication app. I am finding unique way to solve this problem which help to World.

Problem :
[image]

Expecting formatting like :
[image]

Now I want to break down messages and want a ziczac virtical conversation

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: And where is your **programming** problem?

Comment: Right now, I write a simple script which removes date and time from beginning of line and append it on end of line,  As you can see, there is no seems separate message on User1 and User2 conversation that a first problem. Second is ziczac conversation which is most difficult or impossible.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a messager support forum. We are fixing problems in code. Which implies that you have to supply code with a problem.